# How to display CMS static blocks based on store in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, phtml, cms-block

I have created two stores english and german and created static blocks with different contents based on the store in admin.Block Id(test) for both stores are the same but both blocks assigned to respective stores...I need to call static block of english in phtml file. How can I do that?
if I use,`$this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('test')->toHtml();`  nothing will display.

Comment: Can you please post here your phtml file code?

Answer (score 0):

With the following `test` blocks set in English and German stores I can display them in a phtml template with

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Cms\Block\Block::class)->setBlockId('test')->toHtml();?>
```

[image]

Block content will be displayed according to the store view you are in, i.e. English or German.

Comment: can we display only english block set for both?